# Static Front page is not showing after updated the core 6.0.1

Tags: wordpress

[image]After update the wp core version to 6.0.1 the blog page is showing instead of static home page.

Answer (score 0):

First check in Settings > Reading if a static page is set

Comment: Attached the screenshot

Comment: Are you using any page builder?

Comment: nope, i am using acf

Comment: Make sure theme and all plugins are updated

Answer (score 0):

If you are using FSE theme and it has Front Page template, it don`t matter what page is set as front page in reading settings - **Front Page template will be used anyway. It takes precedence over all templates.**
The only way out from this situation that I see - is delete Front Page template.
Link on wordpress documentation:
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#front-page-display
In this situation auto updates need to be disabled to keep it from overwriting parent theme changes.
[screenshot from wordpress admin panel]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCKIl.png

PS *To avoid similar problems in the future I recommend choosing FSE themes without Front Page template. Without this template it is easier to make multilingual websites with Polylang too.*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).